# $_SESSION variable isn't sending data to next page

Tags: php, session-variables

I am working on a php script that sends data over to next page after a successful log in.

I got it to work  100% on my `localhost`.

But now that I uploaded to a server, the variable isn't being passed over anymore.
Furthermore, I had to make changes to my PHP script because it wouldn't execute `header("Location: blah.php)`.

After some research I found that `ob_start()` fixed the problem with the header.

I"m wondering if that is what caused my `$_SESSION` to not send data over to the next page.

Here is the code for the first page:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
    $_SESSION['currentUser'] = $username;
    header("Location: loggedin.php");
```

And this is the second page where I get the session variable `currentUser`.

```
//start the session
session_start();
//grab the current user
$currentUser = $_SESSION['currentUser'];
echo "You're Logged in as: ". $currentUser;
```

When i run the script, it only prints out `You're Logged in as:` with no username.

Comment: did you called session_start(); on first page?

Comment: perfect, that was it, I had it commented out since I was trouble shooting the header problem... Noob mistake, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Call `session_start()` on the first page.